# Rigidbody & Ray alternative or optimization

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics, raycasting

I am creating an **AI** that moves around to certain points, but should interact with ais or objects seen.

#### The **ai** should find other **ai** to comunicate or look for **objects** on the ground.

It works with all those solutions with a low number. But when I have +300 ais the fps drops a lot, caused by Physics2D.FixedUpdate or something related with physics.

#### How would you deal with this?

I have tried those solutions:

---

### **Solution 1**

**AI:**

- Rigidbody2D Kinematic
- SphereCollider2D Trigger
- OnTriggerEnter & Exit Script.

**Objects**

- Rigidbody2D Kinematic
- SphereCollider2D Trigger

---

### **Solution 2**

**AI:**

- Rigidbody2D Kinematic
- SphereCollider2D Trigger
- OnTriggerStay Script executed each 120 frames & a Coroutine to simulate OnTriggerExit.

**Objects**

- Rigidbody2D Kinematic
- SphereCollider2D Trigger

---

### **Solution 3**

**AI:**

- No RigidBody
- SphereCollider2D Trigger
- Cone of Rays executed each 2 second to detect colliders at certain layers.

**Objects**

- No RigidBody
- SphereCollider2D Trigger

---

**EDIT**

In solution 1 and 2, all AI have an "eyes" children GameObject with a TriggerCircleCollider2D and no RigidBody2D, to detect near AIs and GroundObjects.

Comment: Definitely do not use solution 3. If you have a collider without a RigidBody, the physics engine thinks of it as static and optimizes its lookups on the assumption that it shouldn't move regularly. If you do move it, it needs to update those acceleration structures. Doing this a lot (every frame for 300+ objects) will bog down performance.

Comment: If you need 300+ AIs you might want to look into Unity's [ECS](https://unity.com/unity/features/job-system-ECS)

Comment: My AI is well designed. My real problem is detecting ohter entities or random objects with rigidbody and trigger. My pathfindign supports 900 ais at 60fps with a character controller. ECS sounds interesting @ThePumkinMelon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best solution was solution 3.**

With the solutions 1 & 2 with RigidBodies, Physics2D Update Profiler **was around 80%** usage, **now it is at 12%**. I need to remove more RigidBodies from the scene.

**I created a RayCasting & Layer system with Coroutines with the best practices, for example using Arrays instead of Lists.**

Now I can have 1000 agents at 50fps.

Related to **[@ThePumkinMelon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/110967/thepumkinmelon)** recomendation, **ECS**, those links helped me:

- https://unity.com/unity/features/job-system-ECS#entity-component-system-ecs
- https://unity.com/case-study/tic-toc-games
- https://www.youtube.com/embed/GEuT5-oCu_I